# Loop Runs Super Slow

Tags: excel, vba, performance

I've got what is a fairly simple loop, albeit with many defined variables. When I step through the code and get to the loops, I can see the slow down is my If arguments in the last paragraph. Any thoughts on what causes them to struggle so much? Each i pass takes over a second to complete.  Often, I have hundreds of rows to cycle through, so it can take 5-10 minutes sometimes to process this.

The MU variables are on the sheet I'm pulling from, and it may have hundreds of lines. The MD variables are from a huge master sheet, which has about 180,000 rows.

```
For i = 2 To lr 'Loop through each SKU in mass upload, and add the data to the master sheet from it
Application.StatusBar = "Progress: " & i & " of " & lr & " - " & Format(i / lr, "0%")
Set MUSKU = MUS.Cells(i, MUSKUCol)
Set MUClass = MUS.Cells(i, MUClassCol)
Set MUList = MUS.Cells(i, MUListCol)
Set MUHarm = MUS.Cells(i, MUHarmCol)
Set MUCOO = MUS.Cells(i, MUCOOCol)
Set MUHier = MUS.Cells(i, MUHierCol)
Set MUWar = MUS.Cells(i, MUWarCol)


On Error GoTo NextItem
MDSKURow = MData.Sheets("Upload").Columns(MDSKUCol).Find(what:=MUSKU, LookAt:=xlWhole).Row
Set MDSKU = MDS.Cells(MDSKURow, MDSKUCol)
Set MDCLass = MDS.Cells(MDSKURow, MDCLassCol)
Set MDList = MDS.Cells(MDSKURow, MDListCol)
Set MDHarm = MDS.Cells(MDSKURow, MDHarmCol)
Set MDCOO = MDS.Cells(MDSKURow, MDCOOCol)
Set MDHier = MDS.Cells(MDSKURow, MDHierCol)
Set MDWar = MDS.Cells(MDSKURow, MDWarCol)
Set MDLoaded = MDS.Cells(MDSKURow, MDLoadedCol)

If Not MUClass = Empty Then MDCLass = MUClass
If Not MUList = Empty Then MDList = MUList
If Not MUHarm = Empty Then MDHarm = MUHarm
If Not MUCOO = Empty Then MDCOO = MUCOO
If Not MUHier = Empty Then MDHier = MUHier
If Not MUWar = Empty Then MDWar = MUWar
MDLoaded = "Yes"
NextItem:
Next i
```

Comment: [Read the data into an array](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx) and work with the data in memory. Also minimize the number of times you write to the sheet - currently  you're writing cell-by-cell, which will be slow.

Comment: Hmm. I'll have to read up on using arrays like that, it's new to me. Thanks for the link. I'm frankly not sure how I'd modify my sub in that way.

Comment: You can definitely use an array to read the input data, but how useful arrays would be when updating a row would depend on whether the updated columns are contiguous or spread about with other columns in between, and whether your destination sheet has formulas or not interspersed between the cells to be updated (since formulas would be overwritten when dropping an array of values to perform the update to the row).   `Match` is faster than `Find()` but the difference might not be significant with fewer than 1000 or so lookups.

Comment: Use IsEmpty or IsBlank instead of "= Empty"